# JSF Facebook Authentication

Tags: facebook, jsf, authentication

I'm developing an app in which I'd like to enable a user to logon using her Facebook account. I'm using RestFB(restfb.com). So far, I'm able to access the Facebook authentication API using the code below, which executes with no issues:

```
try {
 FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(FB_URL);
 } catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

The FB_URL includes my redirect_url, which is being redirected correctly after user authentication. Authentication returns a code. I'd like to use the code returned to send a request for an `ACCESS_TOKEN`. I figure that the best way to do this is to include a method to be executed in the return URL. This method would be executed as soon as the request to facebook returns with the code response. I also figure that this will be only possible if I can execute an action method from a URL. I've read something about using filters, but its not clear yet. Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to do this. Using

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="code" value="#{loginBean.fbCode}" />
</f:metadata>
```

setFbCode of the LoginBean is executed. I then incorporate this code in the URL I use to retrieve the access token as shown below:

```
if(this.fbCode != "") {
        TOKEN_URL = TOKEN_URL + fbCode + "&access_token=";
        System.out.println("FB Code = " + fbCode);
        try {
                        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(TOKEN_URL);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And to retrieve the token:

```
URL url = new URL(TOKEN_URL);
String token = IOUtils.toString(url.openStream());
this.fbAccessToken = token;
```

Of course surrounded in a try-catch block. It uses Apache's IOUtils to read in the token into a string.